# Ag-Grid Not Supporting Special Symbol

Tags: ag-grid, ag-grid-angular

I tried using Ag-Grid, and faced a challenge to plot the data for Special Symbol, It actually doesn't support the special symbol and doesn't plot it!!

Refer To Example1.png, here the No. Column Doesn't contain data,
but when I remove the dot operator from my script.js file from headerName,
and rowData, it starts [image]plotting it. (Refer To Example2.png)

[image]

Also attached a zip file (Google Drive Link) as a prototype of this problem for your reference!
https://drive.google.com/open?id=1UqyrRtAhg8-HBwqVqUT_CGMhwyr_cOUt

Kushagra

Answer (score 10):

You probably just need to set the [`suppressFieldDotNotation` grid option](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-properties/) to `true`:

> ### suppressFieldDotNotation
>
> If true, then dots (eg `address.firstline`) in field names are not treated as deep references. Allows you to use dots in your field name
>   if you prefer.

(You didn't show any code and I'm not looking in a `.zip`.)

Alternatively, you can have dots in your `headerName`, they just can't be in your `field` name.